Using long exposure photos as x-ray
Would it be possible to light some object from the down size and then put camera above and set it to long exposure to see through the inside. I don't expect to see detailed picture of the inside, but at least some shapes of objects inside the object.
Have anyone tried that? What should be the shutter speed?

Depends a lot on the opacity of the object. Most opaque objects are so opaque that the abysmally tenuous remaining light would be well below all the parasitic lights, and the exposure would be so long that you would have to deal with sensor overheating. This said we all did the test: just forget to remove the cap on the lens.

Why do you think a long exposure would help? If the object to be photographed is translucent, then the light will penetrate through to the camera. If the object to be photographed is opaque, then you are wasting your time with a long exposure because the light is not going to get through. I guess you are thinking about something that is (hypothetically?) just barely translucent? What is the object exactly?
